# Error when trying to change the background color of a text form field

Tags: flutter

I am making a text form field that when it has the focus it has a background color and when it loses it it has another color, this does it, but I have a problem and that is that when I focus the background color changes, but I have to give it double click to load the colors of the decoration:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obscureText;
  final String? hintText;

  const TextFormFieldWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Color colorBlue = Colors.blueGrey.shade800;
    Color colorBlack = Colors.black;

    FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

    final isFocused = useState(false);

    focusNode.addListener(
      () {
        isFocused.value = focusNode.hasFocus;
      },
    );

    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.purple.shade700,
            width: 3,
          ),
        ),
        fillColor: isFocused.value ? colorBlack : colorBlue,
        filled: true,
      ),
      focusNode: focusNode,
    );
  }
}
```

| isFocused=false | isFocused=true |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Not quite clear where you are double clicking?

Comment: `focusNode.addListener(...)` may need to call `SetState(...)`.  If I'm reading `useState` correctly, it shouldn't, but try it.

Comment: @Ruble what happens is that when I click on the input it changes its background color, and the second click makes it take the decoration property, when it should do all that with just one click

Comment: @pgs yes, that was the first thing i tried, but it does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a solution that helped my problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obscureText;
  final String? hintText;

  const TextFormFieldWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Color colorBlue = Colors.blueGrey.shade800;
    Color colorBlack = Colors.black;

    final backgroundColor = useState(colorBlue);
    final focusNode = useFocusNode();

    useEffect(() {
      focusNode.addListener(() {
        backgroundColor.value = focusNode.hasFocus ? colorBlack : colorBlue;
      });

      return () {
        focusNode.dispose();
      };
    }, [focusNode]);

    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hintText,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.purple.shade700,
            width: 3,
          ),
        ),
        fillColor: backgroundColor.value,
        filled: true,
      ),
      focusNode: focusNode,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers.